# Matlab2Tikz+PgfPlots Violating Margins

Tags: pgfplots, matlab2tikz

I use this command in matlab

```
matlab2tikz('fig_blank.tex','width','\textwidth','height','5cm')
```

in order to make a tikzpicture out of this [matlab plot](https://we.tl/QtNFnXY9kx). My MWE in PdfLaTeX

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[h!]
\input{fig_blank.tex}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this[image]

The figure stretches into the right margin... Seems like Matlab2tikz does not count enough space for the tick labels on the left so the figure is too wide. Why is that? I know about workaround like

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\input{fig_blank.tex}}
```

but I rather look for a clean solution. There must be, no? Because this is the whole point of using Matlab2Tikz to have flush and nicely fitted figures.

Any help appreciated, thanks a lot!

PS: Matlab2Tikz and PgfPlots are up to date.

Comment: Anyone a clue? =)

Comment: The link you give to the matlab tikz code is now dead, which may make it difficult for anyone to provide further assistance with this question.

Comment: Check if you have `scale only axis` in the `axis` options in `fig_blank.tex`.